# Node.js workers, do they have independent event loops?

Tags: node.js, event-loop

I am testing the cluster module with a simple webapp and have come across a behaviour that doesn't match the way I thought node works.

My app only has a express router that invokes a blocking fibonacci service (it doesn't use nextTick nor setImmediate).

**Scenario 1 - no workers:** as expected the first request blocks the event loop waiting for the result and the other requests don't get to execute.

**Scenario 2 - with workers:** I start n workers and surprisingly, it can execute n requests simultaneously. I thought that since the master process and the workers share the same socket, they would also share the same event loop. Can someone explain why the can execute in paralell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea of workers is to have different event loops so code can execute in parallel.  This is why you see multiple requests executing simultaneously.